# Nested Dictionary Access and value Return

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, trie

I have a number of nested dictionaries where the key is a character i.e: "D" and the value is a reference to an object containing another dictionary.

EX:

For the words "DAD", "BAD", "DADDY":

```
          B|D
         /  \
       A     A
      /       \
     D         D
    /          /\
   *          *  D
                  \
                   Y
                    \
                     *

If we are accessing "BAD"
    self.child = { B : ref to object, D : ref to object}
    self.child.get("B").child = { A : ref to object }
    self.child.get("B").child.get("A").child = { D : {}}
```

I am trying to access the tree and print all the words out of the tree, either the full tree, or just the portions that match the inputted character. ie: if I input "B" I want "BAD", if I input "D" I want "DAD", "DADDY"

Right now the below code does not return as expected, if "D" is inputted, "DAD" and "DY" are returned.

Self values are initialized earlier in the class.

```
def traverseTree(self, dictionary, baseValue):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value.child, dict):
            if not value.leaf:
                self.accum += key
            else:
                self.l.append(baseValue + (self.accum + key)
                self.accum = ''
            self.traverseTree(value.child, baseValue)
```

I am suspecting that the first chunk of "DADDY" (DAD) are chopped off because their values are not pushed into the accumulator. I believe that with this recursive algo I am visiting each node, since I reach the terminal points, but what is the best practice to recursively access, and store all the word values?

MRE:

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}
        self.terminate = False

    def insert(self, word):
        if len(word) == 0:
            self.terminate = True
        else:
            if word[0] in self.dict:
                self.dict[word[0]].insert(word[1:])
            else:
                self.dict[word[0]] = Trie()
                self.dict[word[0]].insert(word[1:])

    def terminal(self):
        if self.terminate:
            return True

    def autoSearch(self, toSearch):
        if toSearch == '':
            return self.traverseTreeTest()

    def traverseTreeTest(self):
        if self.terminate:
            return [""]
        returnval = []
        for key, children in self.dict.items():
            returnval.extend([key + rest for rest in children.traverseTreeTest()])
        return returnval

word = ["D","DAD", "B", "BAD", "DADDY", "Lad"]
x = Trie()
for y in word:
    x.insert(y)
print(x.autoSearch(''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that at every level you're updating `self.l` and `self.accum`, which modifies the nested objects, so you don't get the full result in the top-level object.

Here's a version that just returns everything as a list, rather than modifying the objects.

```
def traverseTree(self):
    if self.leaf:
        return [""]

    returnval = []
    for key, value in self.child.items():
        returnval.extend([key + rest for rest in value.traverseTree()])
    return returnval
```

This is basic recursion. All cases return a list of strings. The base case is a leaf, which returns a list with just an empty string in it.

The recursive case loops over the dictionary, prefixing the key to the result of recursing into the child, and returning a list of all those strings.

Comment: After testing the solution, the returnval right now only returns the first level "B|D" 

I think that children in the extends, needs to have .child appended to it as self is a Trie type object, while self.child contains the actual dictionary. Appending .child to children doesn't allow the list to return though.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] with the class definition and creation of the tree? Then I can do some debugging.

Comment: `self.child` is a dictionary, but `self.child.items()` returns the keys and values, and the values shold be `Trie` objects, shouldn't they?

Comment: I have added in an MRE @Barmar

Comment: Looks like you've mixed up `self.leaf` and `self.terminal`

Comment: yes just caught that and edited it in the code.

Comment: You can't have a method and attribute with the same name.

Comment: Updated the MRE to change the attribute name

Comment: Why did you change the attribute names between the first code snippet and the MRE? It's confusing when I look at the different parts of the question.

Comment: The problem is with the way you insert leaf nodes. You're not adding it as a new node, you're setting `self.terminate = True` on the same node that also has children. But that prevents the traversal from going into the children.

Comment: So when you have both `D` and `DAD`, the `D` node is marked as a leaf.

Comment: so I have to find a way to say if its Terminal, but still has children continue?

Comment: You should create a new `Trie` node that just has `terminate = True` and no `dict`.